# Batch file Multilines to Single Line Text File

Tags: batch-file, text, multiline

Basically I have a text file generated that creates a text file like so:

Blah1

,Blah2

,Blah3

,Blah4

Now I managed to convert so its a single line, which is what I want... so it now looks like

Blah1,Blah2,Blah3,Blah4

But the problem is there some sort a hidden new line or ascii character. I am copying this into excel and instead of it pasting as one line it pastes as multiple lines again... if I copy it to something like internet explorer address and then recopy it it finally copies correctly...

This is what I am using at the moment

```
    findstr /v /r /c:"^$" /c:"^[\ \ ]*$" "temp.txt" >> "temp2.txt"
    for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i in ("temp2.txt") do @<nul set /p"=%%i" >> "New.txt"
```

Which makes the text look ok but when I copy and paste its obviously not ok.

Basically, how can I remove these HIDDEN LINE BREAKS

Whats really odd is the first Blah1,Blah2 are correct and have no hidden line breaks.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it.

I changed my code to

```
    findstr /v /r /c:"^$" /c:"^[\ \ ]*$" "temp.txt" >> "temp2.txt"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (temp2.txt) do echo/|set /p ="%%a%" >> "new.txt"
```